# Version 2.78, 3D view, Problems displaying a movie clip as background, how to fix it?

Tags: 3d-view, video

I am using Blender Version 2.78,
in the default layout I did the following:

- <kbd>1</kbd> to go into front view
- <kbd>space</kbd> to enter command: allign camera to viewport
- <kbd>n</kbd> to open the box on the right
- selected image>movie clip

However no movie clip showing up, I tried both orthographic and perspective mode, inside and outside the camera. 
When I open an image as a background, it shows up on pressing <kbd>7</kbd> on the numpad. The movie clips I tried to open as background images already worked in blender inside the video sequence editor.

Comment: try disabling "camera clip" and select again the video through the "open" button

Comment: adding that also selecting "image" you can select a movie file, it should work anyway...

Comment: where do I disable  camera clip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant in comments above (if I got what you meant)

As said

- also selecting "image" you can select a movie file, it should work anyway
- or, using "movie" option, try disabling "camera clip" and select again the video through the "open" button

[image]